# Verify that NHibernate has lazy loaded a many-to-one property or not

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, lazy-loading

I have a Project and a Person (somewhat simplified):

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual Person CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting a Project with NH Linq:

```
var projects = from p in session.Query<Project>()
             select p;
var project = projects.First();
```

and sometimes with Fetch()

```
var project = projects.Fetch(p => p.CreatedBy).First();
```

Now, how can I verify in a unit test that project.CreatedBy **is not** or **is** eagerly loaded (and the reverse), depending on if Fetch() was used? In my understanding, using Fetch() should eager load the Person and if I don't use Fetch() it should lazy load the Person.

I've tried

```
Assert.IsTrue(NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(project.CreatedBy));
```

And

```
NHibernateUtil.IsPropertyInitialized(project, "CreatedBy")
```

But they both return true whether I use Fetch() or not. IsInitialized() works fine with collections (one-to-many), for instance Person.Projects, but not with many-to-one...

The CreatedBy property should be lazy loaded but sometimes I want it to be eagerly loaded and I want unit tests confirming that it's working as intended.

The mapping for the CreatedBy property is

```
<many-to-one name="CreatedBy" class="Person" fetch="select">
  <column name="PERSON_ID" precision="10" scale="0" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

I verified the mapping like this:

```
var to1 = NHibernateConfiguration.GetClassMapping(typeof(Project))
    .ReferenceablePropertyIterator.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "CreatedBy")
    .Value as NHibernate.Mapping.ToOne;

Assert.IsTrue(to1.IsLazy);
Assert.IsFalse(to1.UnwrapProxy);
```

Which passes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(project.CreatedBy)` returns true, it's because it is initialized.

If the Person has already been loaded in the session, it will be initialized regardless of whether you fetch CreatedBy eagerly or not, thanks to the Identity Map.

Comment: Can it be that IsInitialized returns true, because that specific property has been initialized with a proxy by NHibernate ?

Comment: No. Calling IsInitialized on an uninitialized proxy returns false, regardless of whether you got it from a property, calling session.Load, or any other way.

Comment: Hum, was afraid of that... This is in a test so all items are created in a setup and all objects are Evicted from the session and the session is Flushed. Probably missed something there then. Will look into it tomorrow. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Calling Evict does not "uninitialize" an already initialized proxy.

Comment: What's a good way to clean the session in a test so that all my tests run with nothing in the session? I thought Session.Flush() / .Evict() should do the trick.

Comment: Well, Session.Evict() did the trick. My mistake was calling Session.Evict on a collection of objects. Session.Evict(projects) instead of Session.Evict(project) for each project (and persons). Once I fixed that in the setup it worked! Thanks for the help Diego!

Comment: There is an `NHibernateUtil.IsPropertyInitialized(object, string)` which did the trick on the property. `IsInitialized` was always returning `true`.

Answer (score -1):

One solution that I see, is the following:

Instead of using an auto-property,
   for CreatedBy, use a 'classic
   property', which uses a backing
   field, like this:

```
private Person _createdBy;

public Person CreatedBy
{
    get { return _createdBy; }
    set { _createdBy = value; }
}
```

In your mapping file, indicate that NHibernate should use the backing field, instead of the property:

```
<many-to-one name="CreatedBy" class="Person" access="field.camelcase-underscore" fetch="select">
  <column name="PERSON_ID" precision="10" scale="0" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

Then, the most beautifull thing you could do, is create an extension method in your unit-testing project which checks whether the _createdBy field has been initialized.

Unfortunately, you cannot access private members in an extension-method.

Therefore, I think you could create an internal method on your Project class which checks whether the _createdBy field has been initialized.
You should also use the `[InternalsVisibleTo][1]` attribute, so that the project that contains your unittests, can access the internal method in your `Project` class.

```
public class Project
{
     private Person _createdBy;

     public Person CreatedBy
     {
        get{return _createdBy;}
        set{ _createdBy = value; }
     }

     internal IsCreatedByInitialized()
     {
          return _createdBy != null;
     }
}
```

In your unit-test, you can do this:

```
Assert.IsTrue (p.isCreatedByInitialized());
```

Note that, if your unittests are in a separate project, you 'll need to indicate that that assembly should have access to internal methods:
therefore, in your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file of the project where the `Project` class resides, you should do this:

```
[InternalsVisibleTo ("MyTestProject")]
```

Comment: I really don't want to rework my entire domain model and mappings just to accomodate a minute percentage of my tests.

Comment: sorry for that.  You just asked people's opinion ...  And 'reworking' the domain model is a bit exagerated.